# Where can I check the voting status of Protocol 20?

Tags: xlm

It says that the Soroban upgrade will start if it is approved by validator voting on January 30th, but where can I check the voting status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These discussions primarily take place in the Stellar Developers Discord server.

Here's an invitation link https://discord.gg/ZJqC8h5z

You can also find more information here https://stellar.org/blog/developers/protocol-20-preparing-smart-contracts-to-stellar